# Smart window resizing with splits in MacVim

Tags: vim

I'm using the latest MacVim. Is there any way to have it so if I open MacVim without a file or with only one file, it sets the window width to n characters? Then if I do a vertical split it will expand the window width to 2n characters? Same for 3 vertical splits but it will stop increasing the width after the window is 3n characters. Then if I close those splits it will resize down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work.  Whether or not a horizontal split has been done, any time a vsplit is created or deleted the window is resized.

```
let g:auto_resize_width = 40
function! s:AutoResize()
    let win_width = winwidth(winnr())
    if win_width < g:auto_resize_width
        let &columns += g:auto_resize_width + 1
    elseif win_width > g:auto_resize_width
        let &columns -= g:auto_resize_width + 1
    endif
    wincmd =
endfunction

augroup AutoResize
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter * call <sid>AutoResize()
augroup END
```

Configure the window width by changing the variable at the top.  You probably want to do something like `let g:auto_resize_width = &columns` to set it to use the width of the original window as the width to resize by.

Things get a little wonky if you have so many vsplits that the window becomes maximized horizontally.  I'm trying to find a fix and I'll post it if I find one.

Comment: My [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102928/automatically-resize-vim-gui-according-to-number-of-vertical-splits/18106180#18106180) seems to be very related, and I think it addresses some issues that are also relevant with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I realized that my first post modified window height, not width. Here is what I meant:**

Here's a quick solution I came up with, but it's not perfect. The function counts the number of open windows and then sets the window width to `original_width * num_windows`. The autocommands call the function when Vim starts, and whenever a new window is opened. You can change the default window width (80) to suit your needs.

```
function! SmartWidth( width )
    let num_wins = 0
    windo let num_wins+=1
    sil exe "set columns=" . num_wins * a:width
    sil exe "normal! \<c-w>="
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter * call SmartWidth(80)
autocmd WinEnter * call SmartWidth(80)
```

This works in the basic case, but does not distinguish between horizontal and vertical splits. I don't know how to do that!

Comment: You could also define a new command (`Vsp` instead of `vsp`) which will execute :vsp and then call SmartWidth()