# Automatically resize vim gui according to number of vertical splits

Tags: events, vim, buffer

I am writing a small plugin for gvim that automatically increases or decreases the width of the gui according to the number of vertical splits.  The plugin works something like this

```
if has("gui_running")
  augroup resize
    autocmd WinEnter * call <SID>ResizeSplits()
    autocmd WinLeave * call <SID>ResizeSplits()
    autocmd BufLeave * call <SID>ResizeSplits()
  augroup END
endif
```

Here `ResizeSplits()` is the function that resizes the gui window:

```
function! s:ResizeSplits()
  let l:count = 0
  windo   if winwidth(winnr()) < &columns | 
        \   let l:count += 1              |
        \ endif
  if l:count > 0
    let l:totwidth = l:count - 1 + l:count*80
  else
    let l:totwidth = 80
  endif
  if &columns != l:totwidth
    execute 'set co=' . l:totwidth
  endif
endfunction
```

The plugin almost works as I want it to, but not quite. It seems like the `BufLeave` event (and similar ones) sometimes executes before windows are closed. This is a problem for instance when I do `<c-w>o` or `:only`.  The problem is that the `ResizeSplits` function does not work, since it still counts the old number of windows.

Is there another autocommand that can be used to detect when the number of windows has been changed, or a `BufLeave`-like event that is guaranteed to be executed after windows are destroyed/removed?

It is trivial to get my plugin to work with mappings, but I am not able to get it to work reliably with ex commands like `:only` and `:close`.

Comment: A workaround is to remap `<c-w>c` to `<c-w>c:call ...<cr>` (similar for other relevant mappings).  This does work for me, but it feels like a rather ugly hack.

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ah, I found that my previous assumption was wrong: The autocommands did execute, and so I really WAS succumbing to the XY problem. I have updated the question with more specific details and more background.

Comment: I don't have gvim laying around to test but I wrote something similar a while back for someone.  I imagine it suffered from the same problems that yours does (probably more since I only use WinEnter).  Might be interesting to see the differences in implementation though.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955473/smart-window-resizing-with-splits-in-macvim

Comment: Yes, the case is the same (at least in principle), and I suspect that your code suffers from the same problem as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work pretty well. First, I rewrote the `ResizeSplits` function:

```
function! s:ResizeSplits()
  let l:curwin = winnr()
  let l:colwidth = 80 + &foldcolumn
  if &number
    let l:colwidth += &numberwidth
  endif

  let l:count = 0
  windo   if winwidth(winnr()) < &columns |
        \   let l:count += getwinvar(winnr(), 'count') |
        \ endif
  if l:count > 0
    let l:totwidth = l:count - 1 + l:count*l:colwidth
  else
    let l:totwidth = l:colwidth
  endif

  if &columns != l:totwidth
    silent! execute 'set co=' . l:totwidth
    silent! execute 'wincmd ='
  endif
  silent! execute l:curwin . 'wincmd w'
endfunction
```

Where the important change is that I have defined a variable `w:count` that is either 0 or 1. The function is used with the following autocommands:

```
if has("gui_running")
  augroup vimrc_autocommands
    autocmd WinEnter    * let w:count = 1 | call <SID>ResizeSplits()
    autocmd BufEnter    * let w:count = 1 | call <SID>ResizeSplits()
    autocmd WinLeave    * call <SID>ResizeSplits()
    autocmd BufHidden   * let w:count = 0 | call <SID>ResizeSplits()
    autocmd BufWinLeave * let w:count = 0 | call <SID>ResizeSplits()
  augroup END
endif
```

This seems to work in almost every case I've tried. There is only one case where `:only` and `<c-w>o` still does not work: If the windows have the same buffer. A simple mapping remedies the `<c-w>o`:

```
nnoremap <c-w>o <c-w>o:call <sid>ResizeSplits()<cr>
```

I will of course be happy if anyone finds a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's no exact event for `:close` / `:quit`; the closest is `BufWinLeave`, but that doesn't fire when the buffer is still visible in another buffer. You could combine that with `BufLeave`, but then have to check that the buffer is actually not visible any more.

To only handle *unlisted* buffers, you can add a condition checking `'buflisted'` in the executed autocmd.

#### Edit after update of question

I don't think there's a way to intercept the corner cases you've described. Especially `:only` could be tricky. I can only propose to work around this with additional autocmds on `CursorHold` and `CursorMoved`. This way, the incorrect state will persist only for a short time.

Comment: Autocommands for `BufWinLeave` and `BufLeave` are not executed for unlisted buffers.

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment is simply wrong. The question has been updated.